# Get min value and index (of min value) from torch.tensor shape=(x,1)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to get a tensor of the min value and its index from a tensor. I have tried `torch.min` but am unsure how the return works to get BOTH value and index of minimum.

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([[10], [5], [8], [2], [8]])

# Ideal output
>>> min_value
[2]
>>> min_index
[3]
```

How can I achieve this using `torch.min`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code example of `torch.min` usage which returns named tuple with both values and indices of min values. It may have multiple value/indices depending on input tensor shape and `dim` parameter.

```
>>> result = torch.min(a, dim=0, keepdim=False)
>>> result.values
tensor(2)
>>> result.indices
tensor(3)
```

or simply `a.min(dim=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Function [`torch.min`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.min.html#torch.min) does return values *and* indices:

```
min_value, min_index = a.min()
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor`. In my case `a.shape=(100,1)` (i'll correct my original question) so I needed to include the `dim=0` flag otherwise it returns a 0 dimensioned tensor with the minimum value. Working solution was @Serhii Maksymenko.